# Can I use an IF statement to multiply one number by a list/range of number in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm using excel and I want to use an IF statement to check if a certain number (x) multiplied by any integer would give me a different certain number (72). If it does I'd like the cell to return (72), if not then I'd like for the cell to be blank.

In my head, such a formula would look something like this:

```
=IF(X*(list_of_integers) = 72, 72, ="")
```

Is this possible? If it is how could I do it?

Comment: Can you mock up the way you see the data being represented as well as the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will return only 72, regardless of the number of times the multiplication equals `72` and will return a null string if none:

```
=IF(OR(8*{4,6,9}=72),72,"")
```

Now if you want to use ranges then you can use:

```
=IF(OR(A1*B1:B3=72),72,"")
```

The difference is that the second must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

If you want a range of numbers us ROW(1:70) which will return an array of number from 1 to 70:

```
=IF(OR(8*ROW(1:70)=72),72,"")
```

This is an array formula that requires the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thought I tried that but obviously not. Probably shouldn't touch formulas.

Comment: This is ALMOST exactly what I want. For your first formula, is there any way I can change the {4,6,9} so it can be a range of numbers. Ideally I would have that part say {1:70}, so it calculates every integer. Thank you!

Comment: Very helpful, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Say we place our number *x* in cell **A1**

In **F1** enter:

```
=ROW()
```

and copy downwards.  In **G1** enter:

```
=F1*$A$1
```

Column **G** represents possible integer products of **A1**

Finally, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(72,G:G,0)),"",72)
```

**NOTE:**

There may be rounding errors if a fraction value is entered in **A1**.

[image]